# mongodb aggregate uniqueness and count at same time with higher level averages

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider this dataset.   For each `name`, we wish to find the average of `x` and the distinct set and count of `game`.   For Steve, this is avg(x)=19, game A is 2, and game B is 1.  For Bob, this is avg(x) = 58, game B is 4:

```
    {"name":"Steve", "game": "A", x:7},
    {"name":"Steve", "game": "A", x:21},
    {"name":"Steve", "game": "B", x:31},
    {"name":"Bob", "game": "B", x:41},
    {"name":"Bob", "game": "B", x:51},
    {"name":"Bob", "game": "B", x:71},
    {"name":"Bob", "game": "B", x:79},
    {"name":"Jill", "game": "A", x:61},
    {"name":"Jill", "game": "B", x:71},
    {"name":"Jill", "game": "C", x:81},
    {"name":"Jill", "game": "D", x:91}
```

**EDIT**:  Answer is below but leaving this incomplete solution as a stepping stone.

I am really close with this.  Note we cannot use `$addToSet` because it is "lossy".  So instead, we group by player and game to get the full list, then in a second group, capture list size:

```
db.foo2.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id:{n:"$name",g:"$game"}, z:{$push: "$x"} }}
    ,{$group: {_id:"$_id.n",
               avgx: {$avg: "$z"},
               games: {$push: {name: "$_id.g", num: {$size:"$z"}}}
              }}
    ]);
```

which yields:

```
{
  "_id" : "Steve",
  "avgx" : null,
  "games" : [ {"name":"A", "num":2 },
              {"name":"B", "num":1 }
            ]
}
{
  "_id" : "Bob",
  "avgx" : null,
  "games" : [  {"name":"B", "num":4 } ]
}
```

but I just cannot seem to get the `avgx` working properly.  If I needed the average *within* the game type that would be easy but I need it across the player.  `$avg` in the `$group` context does not work with array inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      avg: {
        $avg: "$x"
      },
      gamesUnFiltered: {
        $push: {
          name: "$game",
          num: "$x"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      games: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$gamesUnFiltered",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $not: [
                  {
                    $in: [
                      "$$this.name",
                      "$$value.name"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                $concatArrays: [
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ],
                  "$$value"
                ]
              },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      gamesUnFiltered: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Bob",
    "avg": 60.5,
    "games": [
      {
        "name": "B",
        "num": 41
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "Steve",
    "avg": 19.666666666666668,
    "games": [
      {
        "name": "B",
        "num": 31
      },
      {
        "name": "A",
        "num": 7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "Jill",
    "avg": 76,
    "games": [
      {
        "name": "D",
        "num": 91
      },
      {
        "name": "C",
        "num": 81
      },
      {
        "name": "B",
        "num": 71
      },
      {
        "name": "A",
        "num": 61
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This produces a good average but the `games` array cannot be turned into the desired (uniqueName,countOfUniqueName) pairs.   Look at the opening statement again.

Comment: Thanks @BuzzMoschetti for the point out, I just updated my code, let me know if i miss something.

Comment: The `num` field in this example is still incorrect.   It should be the count of all the games of a type, not some value of `x`. Look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!   You need an extra `$unwind` and use `$first` to "carry" the `a` field from stage to stage.  Threw in `total_games` for extra info.   In general, the "group-unwind-first" pattern is a way to aggregate one or more things then "reset" to unaggregated state to perform additional operations with the aggregate values traveling along with each doc.

```
db.foo2.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id:"$name", a:{$avg:"$x"}, g:{$push: "$game"} }}
    ,{$unwind: "$g"}
    ,{$group: {_id:{name:"$_id",game:"$g"}, a:{$first:"$a"}, n:{$sum:1}}}
    ,{$group: {_id:"$_id.name",
               a:{$first:"$a"},
               total_games: {$sum:"$n"},
               games: {$push: {name:"$_id.game",n:"$n"}}
              }}
    ]);
```